# Visual Force Page saving entire Salesforce page within VF page during save

Tags: visualforce

[image]I created a VF page with a "save" button which works but when I save the record the VF page refreshes with the entire Salesforce window within the VF page area. The area circled in yellow should not be there.
Thanks, M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a visualforce page you can set certain parameters at the top of the page. One of them is sidebar="false". When this is false the sidebar will not render.

In this example from one of my page I set the controller, extension, the sidebar, and the header.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EnhancedContactRelatedListCtrl" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Dan but the side bar is still showing inside the VF page.  But if I hit F5 and refresh the page the VF page renders correctly which is without the sidebar.

Comment: Ok.  So when I save the VF page it is loading the entire Salesforce window within the VF page.  Totally weird. I can hit F5 and everything goes back to normal but during save it is placing the entire window view  within the VF page section....

Comment: So I changed the default 'edit' button to utilize this VF page but then I lose access to all of the other fields on the page.  The VF page is just 1 section of the page layout.  Thanks M

Comment: Edit your question to post what you got thus far.

Comment: * With Code, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I have been able to meet the necessary requirements for this VF page.  Is there a way to post the code where it is formatted for others to see just in case they would like to see how the layout was achieved?  Thanks, M

Comment: Edit the question above and then you can paste code into it. There is a button with {} that helps format it. Additionally, you can type 4 spaces at the beginning of a line and then paste and it should format the code as well.